# How to do row-wise subtraction and replace a specific number with zero?

Tags: r, dataframe

Step 1:  I have a simplified dataframe like this:

```
df1 = data.frame (B=c(1,0,1), C=c(1,1,0)
  , D=c(1,0,1), E=c(1,1,0), F=c(0,0,1)
  , G=c(0,1,0), H=c(0,0,1), I=c(0,1,0))

  B C D E F G H I
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
2 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
3 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Step 2: I want to do row wise subtraction, i.e. (row1 - row2), (row1 - row3) and (row2 - row3)

```
row1-row2    1  0    1  0    0  -1   0  -1
row1-row3    0  1    0  1   -1   0  -1   0
row2-row3   -1  1   -1  1   -1   1  -1   1
```

step 3: replace all -1 to 0

```
row1-row2   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
row1-row3   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
row2-row3   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
```

Could you mind to teach me how to do so?

Comment: Somewhat annoyingly, I answered almost the same Q from you a few weeks ago that you accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297505/multiply-a-data-frame-row-by-row/7298277#7298277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using the `plyr` library for things like this using the `combn` function to generate all possible pairs of rows/columns.

```
require(plyr)
combos <- combn(nrow(df1), 2)

adply(combos, 2, function(x) {
  out <- data.frame(df1[x[1] , ] - df1[x[2] , ])
  out[out == -1] <- 0
  return(out)
  }
)
```

Results in:

```
  X1 B C D E F G H I
1  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
2  2 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
3  3 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

If necessary, you can drop the first column, plyr spits that out automagically for you.

Similar questions:

- [Sum pairwise rows with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804498/sum-pairwise-rows-with-r/6804562#6804562)
- [Chi Square Analysis using for loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382039/chi-square-analysis-using-for-loop-in-r/7382303#7382303)
- [Compare one row to all other rows in a file using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289499/compare-one-row-to-all-other-rows-in-a-file-using-r/7289759#7289759)

Comment: thanks for your wonderful advice. This code for a test job, but since my data file is very large, the use of adply seems to be very memory demanding, it waiting time in our supercomputer facility is quite long.  Could you mind to give me some more guidance how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I would do this:

```
cmb <- combn(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 2)
out <- df1[cmb[1,], ] - df1[cmb[2,], ]
out[out < 0] <- 0
rownames(out) <- apply(cmb, 2, 
                       function(x) paste("row", x[1], "-row", x[2], sep = ""))
```

This yields (the last line above is a bit of sugar, and may not be needed):

```
> out
          B C D E F G H I
row1-row2 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
row1-row3 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
row2-row3 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Which is fully vectorised and exploits indices to extend/extract the elements of `df1` required for the row-by-row operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
> df2 <- rbind(df1[1,]-df1[2,], df1[1,]-df1[3,], df1[2,]-df1[3,])
> df2
    B C  D E  F  G  H  I
1   1 0  1 0  0 -1  0 -1
2   0 1  0 1 -1  0 -1  0
21 -1 1 -1 1 -1  1 -1  1

> df2[df2==-1] <- 0
> df2
   B C D E F G H I
1  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
2  0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
21 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

If you'd like to change the name of the rows to those in your example:

```
> rownames(df2) <- c('row1-row2', 'row1-row3', 'row2-row3')
> df2
          B C D E F G H I
row1-row2 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
row1-row3 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
row2-row3 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Finally, if the number of rows is not known ahead of time, the following should do the trick:

```
df1 = data.frame (B=c(1,0,1), C=c(1,1,0), D=c(1,0,1), E=c(1,1,0), F=c(0,0,1), G=c(0,1,0), H=c(0,0,1), I=c(0,1,0))

n <- length(df1[,1])
ret <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
  for (j in (i+1):n) {
    diff <- df1[i,] - df1[j,]
    rownames(diff) <- paste('row', i, '-row', j, sep='')
    ret <- rbind(ret, diff)
  }
}
ret[ret==-1] <- 0
print(ret)
```

Comment: thanks for your wonderful advice. This code for a test job, but since my data file is very large, the use of for loop seems to be very memory demanding, its waiting time in our supercomputer facility is quite long.  Could you mind to give me some more guidance how to overcome this?